# Personalizar vistas de diseño en Rails devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, views, devise

ya tengo tengo diseñado una vista donde tiene iniciar cesión y registrar usuario pero no se como agregar las funciones de  **devise**  en una sola vista [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué tienes hasta ahora?, ¿qué has intentado?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes generar las vistas de devise con el comando `rails g devise:views` y las encontraras en `app/views/devise/` aqui puedes modificar el html como desees o tomar el codigo de los form y usarlo en otras vistas.